# ProgressDialog at the center of Activity

Tags: android, view, progress-bar, progressdialog

I'm trying to put my ProgressDialog at the center of Activity.

Here is my ProgressDialog:

```
final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(ActivityLoginRegistration.this, R.style.ProgressDialogStyle);
    pd.setMessage(getString(R.string.Loading_message_alert));
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();
```

And here is my style resource:

```
<style name="ProgressDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#A5865F</item>
</style>
```

But pd is shown like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNTxU.png)

I've tried tu use `pd.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);`
but it is not working fof me.

How to place ProgressDialog at the center of my Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

To change the progressBar color I overrided the whole bar resource, not only it's style.

progressbar_handler.xml:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="1080">
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="8"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <size
        android:width="48dip"
        android:height="48dip" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#A5865F"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

And then I applyed it to my ProgressDialog:

```
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(ActivityLoginRegistration.this);
    pd.setMessage(getString(R.string.Loading_message_alert));
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    pd.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar_handler));
```

So here is the result: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orKUj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the whole content of your Progress Dialog gravity to centre the progress dialog may be centre but it's width may be `match parent` and so the contents are not at the centre:

**By also adding the line:**

```
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>
```

**The final style will look like:**

```
<style name="ProgressDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#A5865F</item>
</style>
```